# How to find your logs in worldoflogs

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am interested in seeing my logs from raiding in worldoflogs.com after I do something such as LFR (Looking for Raid). How exactly is this done? Is it auto imported into the site? Do I need to manually start a log and then upload it? I'd love any suggestions for doing this and then linking it to a friend to critique it so I can get better at what I do.

Comment: I think it's all explained quite clearly in their help section. Basically it involves joining the site and a guild, downloading a client and enabling the combat log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find logs that you have previously created and uploaded to World of Logs, simply go to the [World of Logs website](http://www.worldoflogs.com/accounts/register/), select the 'Realms' menu at the top, followed by the language of the realm that you play on (English, German, etc).

This will bring up a list of all realms for that language - simply select your realm, which will show a list of guilds, and then select your guild, which will show you a calendar of previously submitted logs.

If your guild doesn't appear, then nobody is currently logging for your guild and you will need to create an account/guild on World of Logs to begin uploading your logs.

In order for your logs to appear on [World of Logs](http://www.worldoflogs.com/), you need to complete the following steps;

- Create an account on [World of Logs](http://www.worldoflogs.com/accounts/register/)
- Activate your account
- [Log into World of Logs](http://www.worldoflogs.com/accounts/login/)
- [Create a 'Guild'](http://www.worldoflogs.com/guilds/create/)
- Download the World of Logs client (requires [Java](http://www.java.com/en/))
- Type /combatlog in World of Warcraft to enable combat logging (this needs to be set EVERY time you want to log)
- Use the World of Logs client to upload your log

For more information on how to use the World of Logs data uploader, see [the official guide on the World of Logs website](http://www.worldoflogs.com/help/client/).